# Which root-finding algorithms can find all the roots including the complex ones of a polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, numerical-methods, algorithms, roots

Which root-finding algorithms can find all the roots including the complex ones?

Comment: Also the Lin-Bairstow method, Newton method, Jenkins-Traub, Durand-Kerner. All methods have to care for the reduced accuracy and slower convergence at clusters of roots (incl. multiple roots). All the sequential ones (that is, all except Durand-Kerner and Aberth-Ehrlich) have to include an intelligent deflation strategy, that is, making sure that the next root of the deflated polynomial is indeed a new root of the original polynomial.

Comment: Please give a more detailed description of your task, make sure that you worked at least through the wikipedia article on root-finding methods, and give your more concrete, specific questions about the task.